# How to use variables set in one function in another

Tags: python

```
def set_values():
    cycle_num = input("Cycle Amount: ")
    probability = input("Probability: ")
    main_menu()
    return cycle_num, probability
def display_values(cycle_num, probability):
    print(cycle_num)
    print(probability)
def main_menu():
    user_choice = input("Choose option 1 or 2")
    if user_choice == "1":
        set_values()
    else:
        display_values(cycle_num, probability)
if __name__ == main_menu():
    main_menu()
```

I am struggling to use variables set in one function in another. I must specify that I am new to python. How could I make this work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think you might want to read about variable scope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules -- Wouldn't hurt to read about returning variables either.

Comment: You're calling set_values(), which returns two values, but you're not storing those values.  They are discarded.  I second @ChristopherSchneider's suggestion that you do some reading.

Comment: Thanks for the comment- I have spent some time previously looking over similar questions but cannot seem to get them working in my actual code(a lot more complicated than the example I provided)

Comment: @SurrealDreams So what would you recommend I did instead to store the variables rather than discard them?

Comment: `cycle_num, probability  = set_values()` - All it requires is assigning the returned values to some variables. However, you'll need more than that to make this work.  See the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a some errors:

- It should be `if __name__=='__main__'`
- You make a recursion when calling `main_menu()` in `set_values`
- As mentioned in the comments you return two values in `set_values` but don't use them
- You would have to use the `global` keyword to get this to work, which is in most times a bad idea
- Maybe you need a proper way to exit your program (like choosing "3")

Try something like this:

```
def set_values():
    cycle_num = input("Cycle Amount: ")
    probability = input("Probability: ")
    return cycle_num, probability

def display_values(cycle_num, probability):
    print("Cycle Amount: ", cycle_num)
    print("Probability: ", probability)

def main_menu():
  cycle_num=0
  probability=0

  while True:
    user_choice = input("Choose option 1, 2 or 3")
    if user_choice == "1":
        cycle_num, probability=set_values()
    elif user_choice == "2":
        display_values(cycle_num, probability)
    else:
      break

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main_menu()
```

Comment: There's no `raw_input` in Python 3.

Comment: @Blender: Thanks, forget what I said. Edited my answer

Comment: @Matt: It "works" because `main_menu()` will be called when this line is evaluated.

Comment: I am not sure which python I am on-using visual studio community- but it will not accept raw_input

Comment: @Matt updated the answer, should work now with Python3 (what is probably what you are using)

Comment: I have a question though- originally I called main_menu() in set_values(). You removed that because it is "recursive" but what I want to know is why it still works and returns to main_menu() with user_choice prompt

Comment: @Matt: When calling `main_menu()` from `set_values()` it simple get called from there. When choosing "2" `main_menu` returns and `set_values` will be finished

Comment: I used this method in my other code and initialised the values to "No selection" rather than 0. This returns No Selection even after adding values in the set_values() equivalent function.

Answer (score 2):

You're having issues with the concept of [scope](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html). When you call the function `set_values()`, you're assigning two variables and are returning them to the original function they were called from. This part is correct.

Where you're running into problems is that your `main_menu()` function isn't doing anything with those values. Since you don't store them, they disappear. A simple solution would be:

```
def set_values():
    cycle_num   = input("Cycle Amount: ")
    probability = input("Probability: ")
    return cycle_num, probability

def display_values(cycle_num, probability):
    print(cycle_num)
    print(probability)

def main_menu():
    while True:
        user_choice = input("Choose option 1 or 2 (ctrl-c exits): ")

        if user_choice == "1":
            cycle_num, probability = set_values()
        elif user_choice == "2":
            display_values(cycle_num, probability)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_menu()
```

Comment: I tried this before and it re-ran option 1 which I do not want it to do.

Comment: @Matt: my apologies, I hadn't noticed that you weren't looping in the code. Should work better now, it's fine on my machine.

Comment: ctrl-c does nothing btw

Comment: @Matt: exits on my machine running it as a script.

Comment: @Matt: that's logical... The values would be unset.

Comment: My program needs that to work though. In my actual code I have done something similar to what the other answer has. I initialised the variables to "No Selection"